# Best way to design a search operator converter in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As my first real-world Python project I'm trying to design a search operator converter using Python. I work as a librarian and use several research databases to search for literature in my day to day work. The functionality of these databases are pretty much identical, but the query syntax is different. Here are two examples of identical searches using different syntax:

*Ovid syntax:*

> dolphin ADJ1 (cat OR dog)

*Ebsco syntax:*

> dolphin N0 (cat OR dog)

I want to make a converter that converts one query syntax into the other.
I started out using str.replace() with a dictionary containing the operators like this:

```
ovid2Ebsco = {' ADJ ':' W0 ', ' ADJ1 ':' N0 ', r')ADJ(':r')W0(', r')ADJ1(':r')N0('}
query = r'dog ADJ (cat)adj1(fish)'
query = query.lower()
for x, y in ovid2Ebsco.items():
    query = query.replace(x.lower(), y)
print(query)
```

While this works to some extent, I had to

1. insert space before and after the operator in order to differentiate between "ADJ" and "ADJ1",
2. had to insert variants like ")ADJ(" in order to get hits if spaces are missing between parenthesis in a query.

I wanted to find a better solution, so my current attempt uses regular expressions:

```
import re
query = 'dog ADJ (cat)adj1(fish)'
query = query.lower()
query = re.sub(r'\badj\b', 'W0', query)
query = re.sub(r'\badj1\b', 'N0', query)
print(query)
```

While the `\b` in the regexes relieve me from having to write out all possible human errors working with parenthesis in a query (e.g. **(cat) adj1(fish)** or **(cat)adj1 (fish)**), I still have a feeling that my approach is sub optimal.

Is there a way to search the query and only do the `re.sub()` if there is a match? Right now I'm updating the query variable for every line, and while it works, it would be great to only perform an update of the query if there is a match with the pattern specified for each search operator.
I also want this converter to be scalable, so that I can include other search operators as well ("ADJ" / "ADJ1" are just two of many).

I appreciate you taking the time to read this - and thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: Note that you can use a function instead of a replacement string, in this way you can access the match object and decide the replacement dynamically allowing you to do just one call to `re.sub`: `re.sub(r'\b(adj|adj1)\b', lambda match: 'W0' if match.group(1) == 'adj' else 'N0', query)`. Note that instead of doing `query.lower()` you can just use the `re.IGNORECASE`  flag to do case-insensitive matches

Comment: `Is there a way to search the query and only do the re.sub() if there is a match?` Well isn't that the purpose of re.sub ? ;) I don't get why you find it sub-optimal ?

Comment: Not sure that it will help but you can also read this https://blog.usejournal.com/writing-your-own-programming-language-and-compiler-with-python-a468970ae6df it might gives you new idea to handle your problem

Comment: Thank you very much, @GiacomoAlzetta. I will try using a function instead - if anything just to try it out. I didn't know you could use a function in re.sub.

Comment: Thank you, @CorentinLimier! And yes, you're right. This is just all so new to me, so I'm constantly second guessing my own code :) I'll read the blog post - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a regex using `\W` (a character that is not a word character) as a look ahead and look behind assertion, the ignore cas flag, and a lambda for the replacement string:

```
ovid2Ebsco = {'ADJ': 'W0', 'ADJ1': 'N0'}
o2E = re.compile('|'.join(['(?<=\\W){}(?=\\W)'.format(k) for k in ovid2Ebsco]), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Then:

```
query = r'dog ADJ (cat)adj1(fish)'
print(o2E.sub(lambda m: ovid2Ebsco[m.group(0).upper()], query))
```

givesas expected:

```
dog W0 (cat)N0(fish)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Serge Ballesta. That works really well - and it also shows a couple of areas within Python I don't fully understand yet, so now I know what to study next. I really appreciate it!